# get exact time in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, date-format, time-format

How to get exact currect time in javascript? For Example when you execute the code you whoud get (2016-02-11 03:11:22:33).

**Note:** There is so many tutorial but none of them gives you the **milliseconds** of current time.

Comment: `new Date()` <- does that, in milliseconds.

Comment: Or are you trying to get that exact format as a string ?

Comment: Maybe you can just append the milliseconds onto the end of your preferred date format? `new Date().getMilliseconds()` will give you the ms.

Comment: @adenoe Yes. Doing hat have made the little problem huge for me...

Comment: @IrkenInvader Ok and how whould you convert that date to localdate?

Comment: JavaScript is a client language, so the date will always be based on local time, unless you specifically use UTC methods.

Comment: It's pretty straight forward -> **https://jsfiddle.net/3dnmLfj4/** (remember to zero pad etc.)

Comment: Did you look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date ? Hard to tell which part you're finding difficult

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `function` should do it :

```
function getTime(input) {
    var date = input ? new Date(input) : new Date();
    return {
        hours : date.getHours(),
        minutes : date.getMinutes(),
        seconds : date.getSeconds(),
        milliseconds : date.getMilliseconds()
    }
}
```

If I would run `getTime()` right now (20:52:49 200ms), I'd get an object with the following properties :

```
{
    hours: 20,
    minutes: 52,
    seconds: 49,
    milliseconds: 200
}
```

---

If you prefer your output to be a string instead of an object, you could also use this function :

```
var getTimeString = function(input, separator) {
    var pad = function(input) {return input < 10 ? "0" + input : input;};
    var date = input ? new Date(input) : new Date();
    return [
        pad(date.getHours()),
        pad(date.getMinutes()),
        pad(date.getSeconds()),
        date.getMilliseconds()
    ].join(typeof separator !== 'undefined' ?  separator : ':' );
}
```

If I would run `getTimeString()` right now (20:52:49 200ms), I'd get this string :

```
20:52:49:200
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/w1bt135u/3/).

Answer (score 1):

Extending John's idea, you can add configuration options to your `getTime` function such as whether the time is 24 hours and if it is UTC.

```js
var now = new Date();
document.body.innerHTML  = 'Local: ' + format(getTime(now, true, false)) + '\n';
document.body.innerHTML += 'UTC:   ' + format(getTime(now, true, true));

/**
 *  Returns an object with time information for a given Date object.<p>
 *  @param date {Date} A date object used to retrieve information.
 *  @return Returns an object containg hours, minutes, seconds,
 *          and milliseconds for the supplied date.
 */
function getTime(date, is24Hour, isUTC) {
  var hour = isUTC ? date.getUTCHours() : date.getHours();
  var meridiem = hour < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';
  hour = is24Hour ? hour % 12 : hour;
  hour = hour === 0 ? 12 : hour;
  var data = {
    hours        : hour,
    minutes      : isUTC ? date.getUTCMinutes()      : date.getMinutes(),
    seconds      : isUTC ? date.getUTCSeconds()      : date.getSeconds(),
    milliseconds : isUTC ? date.getUTCMilliseconds() : date.getMilliseconds(),
    is24Hour     : is24Hour,
    isUTC        : isUTC
  };
  if (is24Hour) {
    data.meridiem = meridiem;
  }
  return data;
}

function format(time) {
  function pad(val, str) { return ('' + str + val).substr(-str.length); }
  return pad(time.hours, '00')         + ':' +
         pad(time.minutes, '00')       + ':' +
         pad(time.seconds, '00')       + '.' +
         pad(time.milliseconds, '000') + ' ' +
         time.meridiem || '';
}
```

```css
body { white-space: pre; font-family: monospace; }
```